Ubuntu won't let me enter my password
When I look to update or install anything with sudo. It tells me 'sorry, try again' twice and then 'sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts' but I am not even given the opportunity input a password.
Example:
Username@Machine: sudo apt update

Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Does anyone know why?

Have you made modifications to any of the files in /etc/pam.d/ (particularly /etc/pam.d/sudo)? or deleted any shared library files (the output of ldd /usr/bin/sudo may be helpful - you can [edit] your question to include it).

I hadn't made any modifications that I know of. I had been installing some software and then this error started. Could it be possible something I installed had modified files?

Yes it's possible - what software did you install, and how exactly? Please [edit] your question to include as much detail as you can remember.

I installed open babel a bioinformatic software. I installed it from the package manager

OK so I think it's unlikely that simply installing the openbabel package (if that's what you did) is the direct cause. Unfortunately there is no simple answer to your question "Does anyone know why?".

Have you run the ldd command I suggested? Did you see any not found in the output? Have you run out of disk space (df -h -x squashfs)? Did you check the /etc/pam.d/sudo file? Has any of the files in /etc/pam.d/ been modified recently (ls -ltr /etc/pam.d)? Does your system use any kind of distributed authentication such as LDAP? Does grep sudoers /etc/nsswitch.conf output anything? Please [edit] your question to include additional information.

I tried 'ldd /usr/bin/sudo' and everything returned normally.
After checking the disk space it looks as though everything is fine
'grep sudoers /etc/nsswitch.conf' does not provide an output

So it's looking more likely to be a PAM issue - is the behavior any different if you use sudo -i (to obtain an interactive shell) rather than sudo somecommand?

Before all, catch one of the 6 reel terminals in Ubuntu with for example "Ctrl+Alt+F2" (F1 to F6 in Ubuntu, Ctrl+Alt+F7 back to desktop) and try to login your user. Then, try to log root with for example
sudo -i

or
sudo -s

and your user password.
If root accept, you have now the possibility to re-precise your user password (or another) with:
passwd <user>

Then simply type
reboot

to give effects to your changes. Controls all's working.
By the same way, another solution is simply to attribute a password to root that have not by definition at ubuntu's installation (security question). Simply type:
passwd

with no user.
Then exit, and become now root with
su -

and the new root password. The old method :)
Another solution the last is to catch the root terminal during grub and explore:
nano /etc/group

Line 21 must be
sudo:x:27:<user>

No, you do not have to reinstall !

when I input :passwd
the command line returned : passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
